# Describing graph in XML

Tags: xml, graph

I have a graph like on the picture below.
[image: graph schema]

How can I describe this graph in XML file?
I think about some kind of lined list of prev and next elements of graph elements. What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinitely many ways to do it. For example something like the following:

```
<graph>
  <nodes>
    <node type="box" id="n1" name="1"/>
    <node type="box" id="n2" name="2"/>
    <node type="box" id="n3" name="3"/>
    <node type="box" id="n4" name="4"/>
    <node type="box" id="n5" name="5"/>
    <node type="box" id="n6" name="6"/>
    <node type="box" id="n7" name="7"/>
    <node type="box" id="n8" name="8"/>
    <node type="box" id="n9" name="9"/>
    <node type="box" id="n10" name="10"/>
    <node type="box" id="n11" name="11"/>

    <node type="null" id="n12"/>
    <node type="null" id="n13"/>

    <node type="junction" id="n14"/>
    <node type="junction" id="n15"/>
    <node type="junction" id="n16"/>
    <node type="junction" id="n17"/>
    <node type="junction" id="n18"/>
    <node type="junction" id="n19"/>
  </nodes>
  <edges>
    <edge from="n12" to="n1"/>
    <edge from="n1" to="n14"/>
    <edge from="n14" to="n2"/>
    <edge from="n14" to="n3"/>
    <edge from="n2" to="n15"/>
    <edge from="n3" to="n15"/>
    <edge from="n15" to="n16"/>
    <edge from="n16" to="n4"/>
    <edge from="n16" to="n7"/>
    <edge from="n16" to="n8"/>
    <edge from="n4" to="n17"/>
    <edge from="n17" to="n5"/>
    <edge from="n17" to="n6"/>
    <edge from="n5" to="n18"/>
    <edge from="n6" to="n18"/>
    <edge from="n18" to="n19"/>
    <edge from="n7" to="n19"/>
    <edge from="n8" to="n9"/>
    <edge from="n9" to="n19"/>
    <edge from="n19" to="n10"/>
    <edge from="n10" to="n11"/>
    <edge from="n11" to="n13"/>
  </edges>
</graph>
```

It still doesn't capture the positions of the nodes and shape of the edges, though.

Verified by the following [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) script that generates a [dot](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dot) file:

```
echo 'graph { rankdir=LR;' ;
open 1.xml ;
my $node_tally = count(/graph/nodes/node) ;

for my $node in /graph/nodes/node {
    if ($node/@type = 'box') {
        echo :s $node/@id '[label="' $node/@name '"]' ;
    } else {
        echo :s $node/@id
            '[style=invis,label="",fixedsize=true,height=0,width=0]' ;
    }
}

for my $edge in /graph/edges/edge {
    my $from = /graph/nodes/node[@id=$edge/@from] ;
    my $to   = /graph/nodes/node[@id=$edge/@to] ;
    echo :s '"' $from/@id '"' ' -- ' '"' $to/@id '"' ;
}

echo '}' ;
```

The dot file produces the following picture:

[image: The generated graph]